# How to change the alarm time in an app in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here I have created an alarm application, so here when I have set the button, it does not convert to stop alarm, and when the time of the clock and alarm time are the same, I want a console like "get up" until I refresh the page, and clockTime === alarmTime always gives the same results, so why does this happen and how do I recover that? Could anyone suggest, please? The code is given below.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
const AlarmClock = () => {
  const [clockTime, setClockTime] = useState(0);
  const [alarmTime, setAlarmTime] = useState(0);
  const [status, setStatus] = useState(false);

  const updateClockTime = () => {
    let currentTime = new Date();
    let hours = currentTime.getHours();
    let minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
    let seconds = currentTime.getSeconds();
    let clockFormat = `${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}`;
    setClockTime(clockFormat);
    if (clockTime === alarmTime) {
      console.log("get up",clockTime ,alarmTime);
      setStatus(false);
    }
  };

  const handleAlarmTimeChange = (e) => {
    setAlarmTime(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleToggle = () => {
    setStatus(!status);
  };

  const handleReset = () => {
    setAlarmTime(0);
    setStatus(false);
  };

  setInterval(updateClockTime, 1000);
  setInterval(alarm, 1000);

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="wrapper">
        <h1>Alarm Clock</h1>

        <div className="containt">
          <h2>{clockTime}</h2>
          <input
            type="time"
            value={alarmTime}
            onChange={handleAlarmTimeChange}
          />
        </div>
        <button onClick={handleToggle}>
          {status ? "Stop Alarm" : "Start Alarm"}
        </button>
        <button onClick={handleReset}>Reset Alarm</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AlarmClock;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comparison is getting failed for `clockTime === alarmTime`. You are storing both states as strings, so you have to check the correct format before comparison. Here's the modified code snippet that works:

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const AlarmClock = () => {
  const [clockTime, setClockTime] = useState("00:00:00");
  const [alarmTime, setAlarmTime] = useState("0");
  const [status, setStatus] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (status && clockTime === alarmTime) {
      console.log("get up", clockTime, alarmTime);
      setStatus(false);
    }
  }, [clockTime, alarmTime, status]);

  const updateClockTime = () => {
    let currentTime = new Date();
    let hours = currentTime.getHours();
    let minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
    let seconds = currentTime.getSeconds();

    if (hours.toString().length === 1) hours = "0" + hours;
    if (minutes.toString().length === 1) minutes = "0" + minutes;
    if (seconds.toString().length === 1) seconds = "0" + seconds;

    let clockFormat = `${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}`;
    //console.log("Clock: ", clockFormat);
    setClockTime(clockFormat);
  };

  const handleAlarmTimeChange = (e) => {
    console.log("alarm time: ", e.target.value);
    setAlarmTime(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleToggle = () => {
    setStatus(!status);
  };

  const handleReset = () => {
    setAlarmTime("0");
    setStatus(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(updateClockTime, 1000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="wrapper">
        <h1>Alarm Clock</h1>

        <div className="containt">
          <h2>{clockTime}</h2>
          <input
            type="time"
            step="1"
            value={alarmTime}
            onChange={handleAlarmTimeChange}
          />
        </div>
        <button onClick={handleToggle}>
          {status ? "Stop Alarm" : "Start Alarm"}
        </button>
        <button onClick={handleReset}>Reset Alarm</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(<AlarmClock/>);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id='root'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maintain all the state variables in type `string`.
`clockTime` and `alarmTime` are set to type `number` with value `0` initially. And then `clockTime` is set to a string value in `updateClockTime`. `alarmTime`is set to the return type of `onChange` event handler of `input`. Type mismatch while comparing two variables will return `false` in most cases.

`clockTime === alarmTime` checks for equality in both value and type. If you want only the values to be checked, you should use `clockTime == alarmTime`, although in your case, I'd suggest to maintain a consistent datatype

Comment: so what thing should I have to be modified?